# Error when trying to count and show total of count in date column in Spark Scala 2.11.11

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am joining 2 tables and that works fine, but when I try to format the date column to get the sum of the count of dates, I get an error on the next line that follows the `.withColumnRenamed` row. I want to display the Package ID, Number of Packages, First Name, Last Name. I am trying to display a list of the top 100 people that have the most packages delivered to them. Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong?

```
 df
     .join(df2, Seq("pId"))
     .select("pId", "date", "firstName", "lastName")
     .withColumnRenamed("pId", "Package ID")
     //.withColumn("Month", 
        month(col("date"))).orderBy("Month").groupBy(col("Month")).count()
     .withColumnRenamed("date","Number of Packages")
     .withColumnRenamed("firstName", "First Name")
     .withColumnRenamed("lastName", "Last Name")
     .show(false)
```

- **Desired Output**
  Package ID
  Number of Packages
  First Name
  Last Name

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're actually running? The code that you have printed should not compile, since there is a line commented out in the middle of your query, breaking the line with `month(...)` in there. Also, can you paste the error message that you're getting? Helps us figuring out what's going on! :)

Comment: That is the code that I am actually running.  It errors out when the .count() is added.  With  "cannot resolve symbol withColumnRenamed"

Comment: [`count()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.count.html) is an action that returns a `Column`. Columns do not have a `withColumnRenamed` method. You need to reorder your code -- do all transformations first, then call action (count).

Answer (score 0):

I used this model and data:

```scala
case class Info(pId: String, firstName: String, lastName: String)

val df: DataFrame = ss.createDataFrame(
  Seq(
    Info("1", "a", "A"),
    Info("1", "a", "A"),
    Info("1", "b", "B"),
    Info("2", "b", "B"),
  )
)
```

And this code:

```scala
df
  .select("pId", "firstName", "lastName")
  .groupBy("pId", "firstName", "lastName")
  .agg(count("pId") as "Number of Packages")
  .withColumnRenamed("pId", "Package ID")
  .withColumnRenamed("firstName", "First Name")
  .withColumnRenamed("lastName", "Last Name")
  .select("Package ID", "Number of Packages", "First Name", "Last Name")
  .sort(col("Number of Packages").desc)
  .show(false)
```

And got this result:

| Package ID | Number of Packages | First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a | A |
| 1 | 1 | b | B |
| 2 | 1 | b | B |